# How to disable MS IMEin google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ime

I understand that there is a CSS property supported by both IE and FF to control Microsoft IME in a particular field like

```
ime-mode: 'disabled'
```

However, this property doesn't seem to be supported in Google Chrome. Just out of curiosity, I did a little testing in Google profile page trying to change a password using Chrome and found out that the MS IME is disabled on the password field. I wasn't allowed to type any characters through IME. How can I achieve that kind of functionality?

Thanks for your help!